# How to enable Stylus input and read the text and save it in a Windows 7 CE Application?

Tags: visual-c++, silverlight-3.0, windows-embedded-compact, windows-7-embedded

I have been working on a Windows 7 CE device. The platform uses Silverlight 3 for Windows Embedded and Expression Blend 3 . The code is to be done in VC++.
I am struck at a requirement.

The user has an option for writing a text at any part of the screen he wants. I have to implement this functionality. After whatever he writes , i need to save it in the way he wrote(handwritting should be the same).

I am novoice in coding as well as in VC++ . I am seeking help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer . WE have the INKPresenter class so we can actually use that :)

I tried and accomplished .. Thanks for not replying